# Backbone Collection model duplicate itself

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

So, I have a **table view (parent)** and **row view (child)**.

I add every row with this code

```
addOne: function (model, base) {
    var view = new App.Views.file_manager_item({model: model});
    base.append(view.render());
},

renderList: function () {
    var _this = this;
    var collection = this.files_collection;

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.templates.table(this.context);

    this.$files = $(document.getElementById('files'));

    collection.each(function(model) {
        _this.addOne(model, _this.$files);
    });
},
```

The ***`renderList`*** fired by:

```
this.listenTo(this.files_collection, "change", this.renderList);
```

*`App.Views.file_manager_item`* is

```
var File_manager_item = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',

    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },

    template: Template7.compile(document.getElementById("fm_item_template").innerHTML),

    events: {
        "click .check": "toggleCheck",
    },

    toggleCheck: function () {
        this.test = !this.test;

        this.model.set({
            "checked": this.test
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log(this.model)
        var context = this.model.toJSON();
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(context);
        return this.$el;
    },
});
```

and the first run return to console

```
child {cid: "c3", attributes: Object, ...}
...
...
...
...
child {cid: "c11", attributes: Object, ...}
```

after **`toggleCheck`** function runs twice

```
child {cid: "c3", attributes: Object, ...}
child {cid: "c3", attributes: Object, ...}
...
...
...
...
child {cid: "c11", attributes: Object, ...}
```

and after every model change, add new **child** in console

```
child {cid: "c3", attributes: Object, ...}
```

Why models are duplicating?

Comment: It's a good question, there's no need to be sorry, in fact, a question should never include "sorry for X" because it's irrelevant ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models aren't increasing, it's just that the views are still alive even if not on the page anymore. It's a kind of **memory leak**. There are multiple item views for the same model, all listening to its `change` event.

A good way to avoid these leaks is to keep a reference to the item view when creating it, then call [`.remove()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on all of them before re-rendering.

Your item view

```
var File_manager_item = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: Template7.compile(document.getElementById("fm_item_template").innerHTML),

    events: {
        "click .check": "toggleCheck",
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },

    toggleCheck: function() {
        this.test = !this.test;
        this.model.set({ "checked": this.test });
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.model);
        // use jQuery because it's already available
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this; // return this to chain calls
    },
});
```

Then the list view

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.childViews = [];
        this.listenTo(this.files_collection, "change", this.renderList);
    },
    addOne: function(model) {
        var view = new App.Views.file_manager_item({ model: model });
        this.childViews.push(view);

        // this.$files is available here, there's no need to pass it around
        this.$files.append(view.render().el);
    },

    renderList: function() {

        // same thing, use jQuery, it's useless to use the native API to them put it 
        // into a jQuery object, unless a marginal performance gain is the goal.
        this.$("#content").html(this.templates.table(this.context));
        this.$files = this.$('#files');
        this.cleanup();

        // collection's each function is just a proxy to the underscore one.
        this.files_collection.each(this.addOne, this); // use the context argument
        return this;
    },

    cleanup: function() {
        _.invoke(this.childViews, 'remove');
        this.childViews = [];
    },
});
```

Comment: OK thanks for this ditailed answer, but I have a little problem. After **cleanup** I still have two copy of **child** it's a bit strange.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin it's possible to be caused by something not in your question.

Comment: And one more thing, I not shure that is necessary, but in **cleanup** function should add *this.childViews = []*

Comment: @vas totally, forgot that detail in haste today.